# XSL Attribute match case

Tags: xslt

I am debugging the xsl stylesheet of someone else and I noticed a lot of template matches aimed at hiding certain content.

```
Ex: <tag hide="X">
```

So their rules go something like this.

```
<xsl:template match="tag1[@hide='x']" />
<xsl:template match="tag2[@hide='x']" />
<xsl:template match="tag3[@hide='x']" />
```

There seems to be a match for every possible tag that can appear in the document, which is around thirty or so. So my question is, is there a better way to do this in xsl than to have a list of template matches for the same attribute match?

Comment: +1 for bothering to clean up other peoples code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@hide='x']" />
```

Comment: is there a difference between '*' and 'node()'?

Comment: Looks like it does the same thing.

Comment: No, they aren't. "*" is for element nodes exclusively, and "node()" matches any node type.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to be more specific about what the template matches, you can do:

```
<xsl:template match="*[
  contains('|tag1|tag2|tag3|' , concat('|', name(), '|')) 
  and 
  @hide='x'
]" />
```

Comment: I like your alternate solution.